# getting a unique count of users in the last 7 days

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, zoo

I have a dataset where I would like to find the people active in the last 7 days (i.e., in the past 7 days). For example,

```
     date<- c('2009-01-03', '2009-01-03', '2009-01-03', '2009-01-04', '2009-01-05', '2009-02-01')
     person<- c('Abe', 'John', 'Abe', 'Kate', 'Jessica', 'Anu')
     df<- data.frame(date, person)
```

I wanted to create a column called last_seven_days_active which takes the unique count of all the people who are active in the past 7 days.

```
     last_seven_days_active
           0
           0
           0
           2
           3
           0
```

I tried this. Any suggestions?

```
   library(zoo)
   df$last_seven_days_active <- rollsumr(df$person, k = 8, fill = NA)
```

Comment: you may need `rollapply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `between` and `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(last_seven_days_active = map_dbl(as.Date(date), 
         ~ n_distinct(person[between(date, .x - 7, .x) & date != .x] )))
#       date  person last_seven_days_active
#1 2009-01-03     Abe                      0
#2 2009-01-03    John                      0
#3 2009-01-03     Abe                      0
#4 2009-01-04    Kate                      2
#5 2009-01-05 Jessica                      3
#6 2009-02-01     Anu                      0
```

Comment: I am getting this message: Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default. can you please advise on how to handle this? thanks so much

Comment: @user3570187 Can you share the package version of `purrr`.  Here, the `.f` is specified with code starting from `~`.  I am not getting an error though

Comment: It worked I think there was a list in my data frame which I presume was causing this issue, it worked when I removed those variables, thanks so much 

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution:

```
df$date <- as.Date(as.character(df$date))

df$last_seven_days_active <- with(df, sapply(date, function(x) length(unique(person[date >= x - 7 & date < x]))))
```

Output:

```
        date  person last_seven_days_active
1 2009-01-03     Abe                      0
2 2009-01-03    John                      0
3 2009-01-03     Abe                      0
4 2009-01-04    Kate                      2
5 2009-01-05 Jessica                      3
6 2009-02-01     Anu                      0
```

Comment: always up for a nice challenge! but great to see you've picked them up as well - many times I only learn through seeing other - even better - approaches. all the best!

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, date := as.IDate(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")]
df[, days7ago := date - 7L]
df[, last_seven_days_active := 
    df[df, on=.(date>=days7ago, date<date), by=.EACHI, 
        length(unique(person[!is.na(person)]))]$V1
]
```

output:

```
         date  person   days7ago last_seven_days_active
1: 2009-01-03     Abe 2008-12-27                      0
2: 2009-01-03    John 2008-12-27                      0
3: 2009-01-03     Abe 2008-12-27                      0
4: 2009-01-04    Kate 2008-12-28                      2
5: 2009-01-05 Jessica 2008-12-29                      3
6: 2009-02-01     Anu 2009-01-25                      0
```

Comment: I was thinking about this optiion.  Good that you came up with